# Can the observation function in a POMDP be a function of the previous state?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning, hidden-markov-model, markov-decision-process

I would like to model my problem with a Partially Observable Markov Decision Process (POMDP) but I have as an observation the previous state $o_t = s_{t-1}$.

However, I see in all formal definitions of POMDPs that the observation function can only be a function of the current state, and previous action: $o_t=\mathcal{O}(s_t, a_{t-1})$ and not a function of the previous state.

A imagine a simple way could be to define $\bar{s_t} = (s_t, s_{t-1})$ but I was wondering if there exists some cases where we can have $o_t=\mathcal{O}(s_t, a_{t-1}, s_{t-1})$.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following I'll switch from your deterministic observation notation $o_t = {\mathcal O}(s_t,a_{t-1})$ to more general probabilistic notation:
$${\mathcal O}(o| s' , a) = P\left(O_t = o |S_t = s', A_{t-1} = a  \right) = P(o|s',a)$$
$${\mathcal O}(o| s' , a, s) = P\left(O_t = o |S_t = s', A_{t-1} = a, S_{t-1} = s \right) = P(o|s',a,s)$$
Let's start with the Bayesian update to the belief state if $a$ and $o$ are known ($N$ is the normalization factor.):
$$b'(s') = \sum_sP\left(s' | o ,  a, s\right) b(s)= \frac1N\sum_sP\left(o|s',a,s\right) P\left(s'|a,s\right)b(s)$$

**In standard case**, following the usual definition of the POMDPs, the first probability is independent on the previous state $P\left(o|s',a,s\right) = {\mathcal O}(o| s' , a)$  and we get the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_observable_Markov_decision_process#Belief_update) POMDP belief update expression:
$$b'(s') = \frac1N{\mathcal O}(o| s' , a) \sum_s T\left(s'|a,s\right)b(s)$$
Which also can be understood as an application of the [forward algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_algorithm) from HMM theory.

**In your case**, the observation probability is not getting out of the summation and the belief update looks like this:
$$b'(s') = \frac1N\sum_s {\mathcal O}(o| s' , a, s) T\left(s'|a,s\right)b(s)$$
I could be missing something, but, actually, I can't see much of the drawback for generalizing the definition of POMDPs like that. It looks to me that most of the standard POMDP analysis, including all the $\alpha$-vector business, can be straightforwardly augmented to incorporate the ${\mathcal O}(o| s' , a, s)$ dependence.

My guess as to why the original POMDP definition was constrained like this, was to keep it similar to HMMs. However, we don't need all the fancier (forward-backward, Viterbi) algorithms from the HMM theory. While similar augmentation for the HMM forward algorithm should also work.

**Finally.** Your case is a bit more constrained that the discussion above - we have perfect observtation of the previous state $s_{t-1}$. So at every point your belief state for the current state $s_t$ is just application of the transition probability:
$$b'(s_t) = T(s_t|s_{t-1},a_{t-1})$$
I think you can go through POMDP theory with that modification, but I suspect that the result will be exactly similar to the approach that you are suggesting - just double the state space $\bar{s}_t = (s_t, s_{t-1})$.